# Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: pg_query(): Argument #1 ($connection)

Tags: php, postgresql

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: pg_query(): Argument #1 ($connection) must be of type PgSql\Connection, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto1\exito.php:14 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto1\exito.php(14): pg_query(NULL, 'insert into dat...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto1\exito.php on line 14

```
<?php
include "conexion.php";
$con = conexion();


$nom = $_POST["nom"];
$user= $_POST["user"];
$rut= $_POST["rut"];
$email= $_POST["email"];
$comuna= $_POST["comuna"];


$sql = "insert into datos values('$nom', '$user', '$rut', '$email', '$comuna')";
pg_query($con, $sql);

header("location:index.php");
?>




<?php
function conexion(){
    $host = "host=localhost";
    $port = "port=5432";
    $dbname = "dbname=db01";
    $user = "user=postgres";
    $password = "password=123";


    $db= pg_connect("$host $port $dbname $user $password");

    if ($db) {
        echo "exito";
    }else{
        echo "error ".pg_last_error();
    }
}
echo conexion();

?>
```

Comment: There are several issues with your code, but the main one is that the `conexion()` function doesn’t return a connection instance.